# MATLAB enable post mortem debugging

Tags: matlab

I heard MATLAB supports post-mortem debugging (enter debugger upon encountering error), how to enable it?

Comment: I first learned it somewhere, then forgot, then not a single search result for "matlab post mortem debugging", then only found it from digging in my notes, so here be it.

Comment: I think that's perhaps because `dbstop if error` or similar isn't quite the same as what is probably usually meant by "post-mortem debugging" - you get to debug a still-live MATLAB process.

Comment: Yeah just superficial guessing. It's a super useful feature, think it should be mentioned in [dbstop](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dbstop.html) or even [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/debugging-process-and-features.html). (Also I think you meant to comment on the answer)

Answer (score 1):

Using [dbstop](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dbstop.html):

```matlab
dbstop if caught error
```

disable with [dbclear](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dbclear.html):

```matlab
dbclear all
```

There's likely a way to disable only it, rather than clearing all `db` stuff, but I'm unaware of what it is (it's not `dbclear if caught error` or `dbclear if error`).